# Transformar dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

Dispongo del dataframe

```
            Acatis  TrueValue  ValorRelativo
Date                                        
2015-12-29  220.43     12.959         12.311
2020-05-13  270.27     12.870         13.234
```

Necesito transformarlo en este otro.

```
          Nombre        Date    Close
0         Acatis  2015-12-29  220.430
1         Acatis  2020-05-13  270.270
2      TrueValue  2015-12-29   12.959
3      TrueValue  2020-05-13   12.870
4  ValorRelativo  2015-12-29   12.311
5  ValorRelativo  2020-05-13   13.234
```

¿Es posible hacerlo aplicando algún método/s ?.

Efectivamente, utilizando "melt" se puede realizar así:

```
p1 = pd.melt(df_analisis, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars =['Acatis']) 
p2 = pd.melt(df_analisis, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars =['TrueValue']) 
p3 = pd.melt(df_analisis, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars =['ValorRelativo']) 

datos  = pd.concat([p1, p2, p3], join="inner")
datos
```

La salida es:

```
        Date       variable    value
0 2015-12-29         Acatis  220.430
1 2020-05-13         Acatis  270.270
0 2015-12-29      TrueValue   12.959
1 2020-05-13      TrueValue   12.870
0 2015-12-29  ValorRelativo   12.311
1 2020-05-13  ValorRelativo   13.234
```

¿Habrá alguna forma más directa?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es una función llamada `melt`, que está presente en la librería Pandas.

Te dejo el enlace a la documentación:

[1] https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

La solución sería algo así:

```
pd.melt(df_analisis, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars =['Acatis', 'TrueValue', 'ValorRelativo'])
```

Comment: Gracias. He incluido en el texto de la pregunta una solución al problema utilizando "melt". Requiere cuatro pasos, en este caso. En DataFrame's con más columnas se multiplican los pasos. ¿Habrá alguna posibilidad de reducirlos?.

Comment: Creo que lo podrías hacer en un único paso:
pd.melt(df_analisis, id_vars =['Date'], value_vars =['Acatis', 'TrueValue', 'ValorRelativo'])

Comment: Efectivamente. Gracias