# Convertir lista en una sola celda de un dataframe en Python

Tags: python, pandas

Mi intención es, que todos los elementos de las filas de una columna queden agrupados en una sola fila de una columna. Hacer lo contrario a un split creo. No se si hay alguna orden para poder hacer esto.

```
fc = ['BEL_1_0', 'BEL_5_1','BEL_1_2','BEL_2_1','BEL_1_1'] 

df = pd. DataFrame (fc, columns = ['place'])
```

y quiero obtener un dataframe como sigue:

```
   place
0  BEL_1_0;BEL_5_1;BEL_1_2;BEL_2_1;BEL_1_1
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo del input y output que esperas?

Comment: Porque si tienes `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[0],[0],[1],[1],[2]], 'b': [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9],[0]]})` y realizas `df.b.sum()` obtienes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]` y si realizas `df.iloc[0].sum()` obtienes `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Y si realizas `df.sum(0` obtienes:                                 
 `a  [0, 0, 1, 1, 2]`   como primera fila y  `b  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]` como segunda fila

Comment: Y si en vez de `sum()` pones `sum(axis=1)` obtienes salidas similares pero la suma se realiza por fila

Comment: ´´´fc = ['BEL_1_0', 'BEL_5_1','BEL_1_2','BEL_2_1','BEL_1_1'] 

df = pd. DataFrame (fc, columns = ['place'])```

y quiero obtener de output una sola columna en forma de dataframe con todos los valores BEL en la misma fila separados por punto y coma

Comment: seria mejor que edites la pregunta y trata de darle formato a tu input y output como aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367906/transformar-dataframe

Comment: @Victor, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer muy fácilmente con `join`

```
import pandas as pd

fc = ['BEL_1_0', 'BEL_5_1','BEL_1_2','BEL_2_1','BEL_1_1'] 

df = pd.DataFrame({'place': ';'.join(fc)}, index=[0])
```

Esto devuelve:

|  | place |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | BEL_1_0;BEL_5_1;BEL_1_2;BEL_2_1;BEL_1_1 |